# Out of memory trying to convert csv file to parquet using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parquet

I am trying to convert a very large csv file to parquet.

I have tried the following method:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/amex-default-prediction/train_data.csv')
df1.to_parquet('/kaggle/input/amex-default-prediction/train.parquet')
```

but `pd.read_csv` throws `Out Of Memory Error`

Is there any way to convert to the file without loading it entirely ?

Comment: I think you need to read the csv using pyarrow (maybe with the open_csv() method due to memory constraints) and then write it as a parquet "partitioned dataset" using the pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset() method. You can get some info here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#partitioned-datasets-multiple-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the memory problem, you can first import the data with the chunck method of pandas and save each chunck as a parquet file. So for example for your case, create a folder "train_data", and in this folder you save the different parquet files that correspond to the chuncks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import csv2parquet
from subprocess import run
import fastparquet
import sys
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

path ="C:/.../amex-default-prediction/"
parquet="parquet/"
#create new folder train_data
path_train_data="train_data/"


def get_path_parquet(file):
    if file.split('.')[0]=="sample_submission":
        return path_sample_submission
    elif file.split('.')[0]=="test_data":
        return path_test_data
    elif file.split('.')[0]=="train_data":
        return path_train_data
    elif file.split('.')[0]=="train_labels":
        return path_train_label
def csv_to_parquet(df,title, path,i):
    """
    Convert Csv files to parquet
    df    : csv data
    title : name data
    path  : folder into the save parquet data
    """
    try:
        title_prefix=title.split(".")[0]+str(i)
        out_title = path + f'\\{title_prefix}.parquet'
        df.to_parquet(out_title, engine='fastparquet')
    except:
        sys.exit(-1)
def loding_csv_with_chunk(path,file):
    try:
        chunk_csv= pd.read_csv(path + f'\\{file}', low_memory=False, chunksize = 5000)
        #df = pd.concat(chunk for chunk in chunk_csv)
        return chunk_csv
    except:
        sys.exit(-1)
        

def read_partition_parquet():
    dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(path_train_, use_legacy_dataset=False)
    data=dataset.read().to_pandas()
    return data


#csv_df
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file[-4:]==".csv":
        
        print("begin process for : "+str(file)+ "....")
        #csv_df = pd.read_csv(path + f'\\{file}')
        ##load data with chunck method
        chunk_csv = loding_csv_with_chunk(path,file)
        ##for each chunck save the data on parquet format 
        for i, df_chunk in enumerate(chunk_csv):
            print(df_chunk.shape)
            title_prefix=file.split(".")[0]+str(i)
            out_title = path+parquet+get_path_parquet(file) + f'{title_prefix}.parquet'
            df_chunk.to_parquet(out_title, engine='fastparquet')
        #csv_to_parquet(csv_df,file, path)
        print("end process for : "+str(file)+ "....")
    else:
        continue
```